# プログラム実行時「python nameerror name 'ture' is not defined」と表示されてしまう原因は何ですか？

Tags: python

python経験暦３ヶ月の人です。何回も書き直しても

```
python nameerror name 'ture' is not defined
```

と表示されてしまいます。

ちなみにこのパソコンはWindows7なのですが、そのことが関係しますか？

Comment: エラーメッセージだけではなく、実際のコードも質問に含めるようにしてください。質問は後からでも [編集] することができます。

Answer (score 1):

スペルが間違っているのと最初の`t`が大文字でないからでは？ `True`に変えてみてください。

**追記：**

以下のように過去に同様の質問が有ったようです。
[pythonプログラム実行時に「NameError: name 'true' is not defined」とエラーになってしまう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44160/26370)

---

本当にこの名前`ture`という何かを使いたかったのであれば、事前に定義や初期化していない状態で値を代入しようとしたり、関数やメソッドのパラメータに指定しようとした可能性が考えられます。

エラーメッセージ自身はもっと行数があるはずで、そこにソースコードの何行目(更には何桁目)で発生しているか、といった情報が出ているはずです。

実行しようとしているソースコードや使用しているテストデータと、発生しているエラーメッセージの全てを質問記事に追記してみてください。

それらが巨大で掲載するのが大変ならば、問題を再現できる状態で最小限のサイズまで削減してから追記してみてください。

案外そうした作業中に自分で原因を特定出来たりするものです。